# ZSH alias not working

Tags: zsh

I am trying to get the following alias setup but I think I am in quote hell

```
alias apps='dpkg -l | awk "{print $2 "\t" $3}" | fzf'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want *$2* and *$3* variables to be evaluated by the shell but your alias will do:

```
dpkg -l | awk "{print $2 "\t" $3}" | fzf
```

Since you awk expression is between doubles quotes, shell will take your variables.

To avoid that you can use:

```
alias test='dpkg -l | awk "{print \$2 \"\\t\" \$3}" | fzf'
```

or

```
alias test="dpkg -l | awk '{print \$2 \"\\t\" \$3}' | fzf"
```